# React-Semantic UI dispatch event not working

Tags: javascript, reactjs, preact

I am creating a text input with react semantic UI that will put text when a button clicked. Everything is working well except that this action doesn't fire the `onchange` event so the state wouldn't be updated.

Here is my function that appends text to the input

```
const putTextAtCursor = (text, inputID) => {
  let inputElement = document.getElementById(inputID);
  console.log({ inputElement, inputID });
  let cursorPosition = 0;
  if (document.selection) {
    inputElement.focus();
    let selectionRange = document.selection.createRange();
    selectionRange.moveStart("character", -inputElement.value.length);
    cursorPosition = selectionRange.text.length;
  } else if (
    inputElement.selectionStart ||
    inputElement.selectionStart == "0"
  ) {
    cursorPosition = inputElement.selectionStart;
  }
  let origValue = inputElement.value;
  let newValue =
    origValue.substr(0, cursorPosition) +
    text +
    origValue.substr(cursorPosition);

  inputElement.value = newValue;
  let start = inputElement.selectionStart;
  inputElement.selectionStart = inputElement.selectionEnd = start + text.length;
  let event = new UIEvent("change");
  inputElement.dispatchEvent(event);
  inputElement.focus();
};
```

the `dispatchEvent` seems doesn't fired. Full demo is [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/semantic-ui-react-example-qj0no)

How to solve this?

Comment: What do you want to get after button "add tag" click?

Comment: the input's onchange to be fired

Comment: so, when someone will click on addtag button, you want to have under this the text "url":"<sampletag:1>"?

Comment: yeees, you got me, because the text that added does not trigger the onchange event

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use this code:

```
let input = inputElement;
let lastValue = input.value;
input.value = newValue;
let event = new Event('input', { bubbles: true });
let tracker = input._valueTracker;
if (tracker) {
    tracker.setValue(lastValue);
}
input.dispatchEvent(event);
```

Instead this:

```
  inputElement.value = newValue;
  let start = inputElement.selectionStart;
  inputElement.selectionStart = inputElement.selectionEnd = start + text.length;
  let event = new UIEvent("change");
  console.log(inputElement.onchange, "io");
  inputElement.dispatchEvent(event);
```

This is because of version of React. Everything to understand this situation is in this post: https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/11488

Comment: but why when i log the tracker returning undefined?

Comment: Can you give me some print screen of this situation? I've copied your code, and added mine, and everything works fine

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/WmCdYNM
i just console.log({tracker}) because i'm curious what _valueTracker is